# Python how to get value from config toml file

Tags: python, toml

Hi I am trying to get the value from config.toml file.
Below is the config.toml file:

```
path.repo_uat7="/home/developer/user1"
path.repo_uat12="/home/repo/user21"
database.hostname.uat7="dbname7"
database.hostname.uat12="dbname12"
database.port="1825"
db.cluster.nodes=["cluster1:15382","cluster2:15382"]
```

I tried getting the value of path.repo_uat7 and path.repo_uat12  by the below python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import toml
import sys, os

data = toml.load("uat7.toml")
print (toml.dumps(data))

desc = str(sys.argv[1])
st = desc.split(".")
st1 = st[0]
st2 = st[1]


for k1, v1 in data.items():
    if k1 == st1:
     for k2, v2 in v1.items():
       if k2 == st2:
         print(v2)
```

This is how I run my code: python getvar.py path.repo_uat7. I am getting output as

```
/home/developer/user1
```

But what if I want to get the database or db.cluster.nodes, how to iterate multiple times, I am not getting perfect solution. Please help.

Comment: The toml is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to iterate. You can index `data` directly with the given keys. Replace the `for` loop with

```
print(data[st1][st2])
```

and you get the same output.

Similarly, you can write `data['database']['hostname']['uat7']` to get `"dbname7"`, etc.